# IntegrityError using fixtures with Django 1.11 TestCase

Tags: django, django-testing, django-1.11

I'm writing a test in Django 1.11 and trying to load some fixture data into my local `sqlite` database (retrieved from the real database via `manage.py dumpdata`) like so:

```
class MyTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = [os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'myapp', 'tests', 'fixtures.json')]
```

Part of the fixture data is `User` models where we have a custom User with a different `USERNAME_FIELD`, so all of the `username` fields on each of our records is blank.

However, when I try and run my test using my fixture, I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '.../fixtures.json': Could not load myapp.CustomUser(pk=41): column username is not unique
```

pk 41 is the second `CustomUser` record in my fixtures.json.  How can I tell Django's testing framework to ignore the constraint it thinks it needs to enforce, or otherwise get my fixture data loaded for testing?

Comment: This is why fixtures suck, they don't keep up with your schema.  Recommend to throw them away and use [factory boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#django) instead.  If that's too much work, maybe just regenerate the user fixtures with some bogus usernames (e.g. UUID4s).

Comment: Yeah, we're using factory boy for some things but it'd be too much work to use it for my particular case.  I went with just generating usernames with `uuid.uuid4()` like you suggested.  Thanks!